# Check all checkboxes by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to check all checkboxes by jquery in my app. I have the following layout:

```
.row
    .col-md-12
      = field_set_tag t('car.places')
      %input{type: "checkbox", id: "selectAll"}/
      = t('car.select_all_locations')

      %table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.centered#car_locations
        %thead
          %tr
            %th{width: "200"}= t('cars.select')
            %th{width: "300"}= t('cars.your_locations')
            %th{width: "200"}= t('cars.location_type')
            %th{width: "400"}= t('cars.after_hours_availability')
        %tbody
          - Location.all.each do |location|
            %tr
              %td= check_box_tag "car[location_ids][]", location.id, @car.location_ids.include?(location.id), id: "test" 
              %td= location.name
              %td= location_type(location)
              %td= after_hours_availability(location)
```

Which way is the best to to this thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#allcb').change(function () {
      $('tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

[Demo:Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tss8/21/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','#selectAll',function () {
    $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To check all the checkboxes on page, You can use:

```
 $("input:checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this script

```
$(function) {
$('table th input:checkbox').on('click' , function(){
var that = this;
$(this).closest('table').find('tr > td:first-child input:checkbox')
.each(function(){
this.checked = that.checked;
$(this).closest('tr').toggleclass('selected');
});
});
```

and in your form/index

```
<%= check_box_tag "locations[]", location.id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#selectAll').click ->
    if(this.checked)
        $(':checkbox').each ->
        this.checked = true
    else
        $(':checkbox').each ->
        this.checked = false`

Answer (score 1):

Hi Just giving a simple demo for that

### html

```
   <section>
     <ul id="ul1">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk1"/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk2"/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk3"/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk4"/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk5"/></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" name="bt1" id="bt2" value="check all"/>

</section>
```

### js

```
   $("#bt2").on("click",function(){

    $("ul#ul1").find("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked","checked");

   });
```